# Akka actor remote dissociation from sending a delayed response

Tags: scala, akka, actor, future, remote-server

So I have a client server based program, where the client will send a request to the server, the server will do a computation and response. This is done via ask.

Specifically the client will receive a message from the client app and send call ask

```
      val response = ask(actorRef, SessionMessage(token, message)).mapTo[ResponseMessage]
```

The server will receive it like so

```
val response = sessionMessage.message match {
      case message: message1 =>
        ask(actorSet.actor1,message)
      case message: message2 =>
        ask(actorSet.actor2,message)
```

Where the actorset is literally a set of the different actors.

I then collect the result and send back to the sender

```
val responseResult = response.mapTo[ResponseMessage]
    responseResult pipeTo sender
```

The problem I'm running into is that for some of the requests, the database query can take a while (5-10 minutes) and when the query completes it sends to dead letters and I get a dissociation and it is unable to associate again and sends to dead letters.

I thought that because it took so long, that the sender would time out (or specifically the sender reference) so I stored the sender reference as a val, and confirmed that by doing this I the sender reference was lost. However, as soon as as the query finishes and I pipe it to the correct sender, it dissociates. Even other queries that take a minute or so don't seem to suffer this problem, only ones that last for a few minutes dissociate and I need to restart the server or the server will keep sending to dead letters.

Even if I do a onComplete then send on success or do an Await.result, the same issue occurs, as soon as it tries to send the message (after completion) the server dissociates and sends to dead letters.

I'm very much at lost as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are into is that `ask` itself has a timeout, which is separate from a timeout you might specify in `Await.result`. The full signature to `ask` is:

```
def ask (actorRef: ActorRef, message: Any)(implicit timeout: Timeout): Future[Any]
```

This means that if you did not manually provide a value for `timeout` and did not define an implicit yourself, you must be inheriting one via one of your imports.

To extend the timeout for your particular `ask`, simply call it with one:

```
ask(actorRef, SessionMessage(token, message))(15.minutes).mapTo[ResponseMessage]
```

or if this applies to all `ask`s in scope, declare your own `implicit`:

```
implicit val timeout = Timeout(15.minutes)
```

Comment: Except the ask pattern requires the actor to have a timeout, which I have defined at a higher level (specifically where the actors are created).